# Query posts by current ACF meta key value on single page as related posts

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, meta-value

I would like to Query a custom post by the current ACF Meta Key values on a single custom post type page. I currently have a CPT called "news", a single-news.php page and ACF checkbox labeled news_type. Within page I would like to find the current news_type Meta_key value and query the posts that contain the same value, like a related news section. After some research I found that it is possible to query by meta_key like so:

```
<?php

// args
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => 6,
    'post_type'     => 'news',
     'meta_key'      => var_dump( $my_current_meta_value ),
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul class="row small-up-2 medium-up-2 large-up-1">
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="column column-block">
            <div class="large-10 columns large-centered">

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <article>

                     <?php
                         if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                             the_post_thumbnail();
                         }
                     ?>
                     <hr>

     <h4 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h4>

             </article>
            </a>
        </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
<ul>
```

I am aware that wordpress lets you `get_post_meta()` and would look like this

```
<?php $my_current_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'news_type', true ); ?>
```

based on this approach I should be able to pass my variable through the meta_value like so:

```
 <?php
    
    // args


$my_current_meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'news_type', true );

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => 6,
        'post_type'     => 'news',
        'meta_key'      => ''.$my_current_meta_value.''

    );
    
    
    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    ?>
    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <ul class="row small-up-2 medium-up-2 large-up-1">
        <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="column column-block">
                <div class="large-10 columns large-centered">
    
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <article>
    
                         <?php
                             if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                 the_post_thumbnail();
                             }
                         ?>
                         <hr>
    
         <h4 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h4>
    
                 </article>
                </a>
            </div>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
    <ul>
```

The True parameter above is said to grab the first associated value with the meta_key and query based on that but this doesn't seem to be working and i get a Notice: Array to string conversion. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: What line is the Notice on?

Comment: @mozboz the notice is on line `meta_key'      => ''.$my_current_meta_value.''`

Comment: looks ok to me. two things: 'numberposts' isn't a valid parameter for WP_Query args, and on the meta key line `''` is an empty string, so appending an empty string onto something does nothing. Are sure this is your running code that's generating this error? get_post_meta with `single` set to true can not return an array

Comment: that line doesn't do any array to string conversation - it might be useful to paste the whole error message you're getting

Comment: @theartist "pass my variable through the meta_value" - but you actually passed it to `meta_key` and not `meta_value`. And if `$my_current_meta_value` is an array, then you can't do the `''.$my_current_meta_value`. Try `var_dump( $my_current_meta_value );`

Comment: @SallyCJ where would that go? I have updated my code above but i keep getting `array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "Work" }` printed in the loop. The "work" value is correct and the appropriate posts are displaying but again i get the array printed. Also how would i go about eliminating the current post from display in the loop? I appreciate the help

Comment: The `var_dump()` is really just for *checking* the `$my_current_meta_value` type and value. And if it's an array, then unfortunately, it can't be used for querying the related posts by the same meta key. You should fix the checkbox field so that it's a single value and not an array, or much better, use a custom taxonomy and not the meta `news_type`.